# Single file output from multiple source files with fluent-bit

Tags: amazon-s3, fluent-bit

We are using fluent-bit to capture multiple logs within a directory, do some basic parsing and filtering, and sending output to s3.  Each source file seems to correspond to a separate output file in the bucket rather than a combined output.

Is it possible to send multiple input files to a single output file in fluent-bit, or is this simply how the buffer flush behavior works?

Here is our config for reference:

```
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 1
        Log_Level warn
        Parsers_File parsers.conf
        Parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
        Health_Check Off
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        storage.path /tmp/fluentbit/
        storage.max_chunks_up 128

    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser docker, cri
        Tag kube.*
        storage.type filesystem
        Mem_Buf_Limit 10MB
        Buffer_Chunk_Size 2M
        Buffer_Max_size 256M
        Skip_Long_Lines On
        Skip_Empty_Lines On

    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Keep_Log Off
        Merge_Log_Key msg-json
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
        Cache_Use_Docker_Id On

    [FILTER]
        Name nest
        Match kube.*
        Operation lift
        Nested_under kubernetes
        Add_prefix kubernetes_

    [FILTER]
        Name nest
        Match kube.*
        Operation lift
        Nested_under kubernetes_labels
        Add_prefix kubernetes_labels_

    [FILTER]
        Name aws
        Match *
        imds_version v1
        az true
        ec2_instance_id true
        ec2_instance_type true
        private_ip true
        account_id true
        hostname true
        vpc_id true

    [OUTPUT]
        Name s3
        Match *
        bucket <bucket name redacted>
        region us-east-1
        total_file_size 100M
        upload_timeout 60s
        use_put_object true
        compression gzip
        store_dir_limit_size 500m
        s3_key_format /fluentbit/team/%Y.%m.%d.%H_%M_%S.$UUID.gz
        static_file_path On
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send multiple input files to single output file.

The issue here might be with your use of the `s3_key_format`.

Your current file name format is `'/fluentbit/team/%Y.%m.%d.%H_%M_%S.$UUID.gz'` and this has a UUID which causes each input file being written to a separate output file in S3.

To combine and send to single output file, just modify it to `'/fluentbit/team/%Y.%m.%d.gz'`

Comment: With this method the files get overwritten and still contain only a single source file's log data.  We took it a bit further and went with `%Y.%m.%d.%H_%M_%S.gz` but you get multiple files again on each buffer flush, each containing data from a single source file.

Comment: there is a flag called `static_file_path` making it true will disable random characters in output block